# How do I use a variable rather than a hard coded string when updating a text file with python?

Tags: python

I've written a small script to append a character to the end of each line of a text file, "," in my case.

This will be shared with my team, so rather than have them update the script itself I thought it would be easier to simply define a variable at the start they can change.

However, it takes 'char' as a literal string and appends 'char' rather than ',' in the test file. If I swap `char\n` back to `,\n` it appends a comma correctly.

How do I fix this?

```
file = 'test.txt' # file to append text to, keep the '' 
char = ','

newf=""
with open(file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        newf+=line.strip()+'char\n'
    f.close()
with open(file,'w') as f:
    f.write(newf)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Also note that `f` is closed after you leaved the indented `with` block so no need to call `f.close()`.

Comment: Check f-strings formatting. https://datagy.io/python-f-strings/  In your case, it can be something like `newf += f'{line.strip()}{char}\n'`

Comment: You might also improve your code by using something like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), which would allow users to provide `char` and `file` from the commandline without having to edit the script at all.

Comment: I cant answer anymore since this was closed.  However if youre just updating a file Id encourage you to do it in place instead of saving everything to a string and then writing it. Heres some code using in_place which can be installed with pip install in_place:

import in_place
charToAdd = ','
with in_place.InPlace('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        file.write(line.strip() + charToAdd + '\n')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were passing variable name as string instead of passing the variable. Try this:

```
file = 'test.txt' # file to append text to, keep the ''
char = ','

newf=""
with open(file,'r') as f:
  for line in f:
      newf+=line.strip()+char+'\n'
  f.close()
with open(file,'w') as f:
  f.write(newf)
  f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As `char` is a variable you have to place it outside the quotation marks, otherwise it is interpreted as a string.

```
file = 'test.txt' # file to append text to, keep the '' 
char = ','

newf=""
with open(file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        newf+=line.strip()+ char + '\n'
with open(file,'w') as f:
    f.write(newf)
```

Comment: not outside the brackets, outside the quote marks which delimit the string

Comment: sorry, you are right of course, I will edit the answer